# How to add comment in Clickhouse SQL query

Tags: clickhouse

I met this strange thing and want to understand how you handle it.

I am using Monaco editor to write sql query and then using node clickhouse library to run the query, so, in the editor, user entered this:

```
-- Explain
select * from table 1
```

and the query sent to clickhouse is this:

```
-- Explain\nselect * from table 1
```

But when running this, I got error

```
:"SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 2\n at pa...
```

Seemed the comment here is causing the error.

Can you tell me how to put comment into the query and send to clickhouse to run?

Comment: But this is not a Clickhouse error. It's the problem is in "node clickhouse library"

Answer (score 0):

Have you already found the solution to your problem?
Otherwise I can advise you to use the "multi-line comments" as follows:

```
/* Explain */
SELECT * 
FROM table1
```

It gets around the problem to achieve the desired result.